# Is it possible to limit the user from writing data?

Tags: 12.04

I have created different users and set their home directories to particular folders. I have limited the users' access other than their directories.
How could I limit users from writing data?

Comment: Write data to where?

Comment: it just storing data may be i create file or any thing that consumes disk space

Comment: Not allowing writing data in their own HOME directory will break their login (files need to be written in /home/$USER by the system with the user name. UNLESS we are talking about ftp I would not touch /HOME/$USER

Comment: Rinzwind, it's not that big of a deal. Not every file needs to be kept writeable. As long as files are still kept readable to the user, all works out fine.

Comment: i don,t want to restrict writing data in their own HOME directory , i want they just able to write in home directory with limited data size @Rinzwind

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. Please try to explain with an example.

Comment: It sounds like the question is about user/group __disk quotas__

Comment: Naveen, his question makes perfect sense if you understand English.

Comment: +1 steeldriver. Yes that sounds like a disk quota thing. @mmstick no it is not.

Comment: Thanks steeldriver , I am not having any knowledge about user/group disk quotas , but how can it will be useful to me @steeldriver

Comment: @Dipak the link above points to this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/ and it explains how to set up a partition with limited disc space per user.

Comment: @Rinzwind it seems to be i need to install quota and modify /etc/fstab and reboot system. i want to add user at run time using scripts as per need , and i am not reboot system because it will break other users from uploading data to their directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `chmod` and `chown` command using `man`. You can modify files and directories so that they belong to root and are not writeable by anyone other than root, for example.

Example (as root): `chown root:root file`

Comment: Careful: do this in `/home` or with some files in `/home/$USER/` and the user will not be able to login.

Comment: Laziest answer I've ever seen on AskUbuntu!

Comment: Who needs a wall of text when a concise answer is all you need? There's a difference between laziness and being concise.